# change netbeans C project release and debug folder

Tags: c, debugging, netbeans, directory, release

I'm using Netbeans for C/C++ projects and I'd like to know how I can change the output directory for debug/release.

By default, the output path for a project is

```
<projectname>\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\<projectname>.exe
```

I checked the project properties but I didn't found anything that made sense for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it here:

click on project -> **`Properties`** -> **`Build`** -> **`Linker`** there you can set the path at **`Output`**.

The default one uses variables for path, but you can set as you like.

*Defualt explained:*

```
${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/<Your Project Name>
      ^            ^              ^
      |            |              |
  Destination dir  |          Target platform
                   |
      Configuration, eg. debug or release
```